# If meta_value = 'yes', then add class?

Tags: php

`meta_key=_jsFeaturedPost`  `meta_value=yes`

I have posts where some have meta keys/values and some don't. I would like to target the ones with the meta keys that have a value of 'yes' and add a CSS class to those posts so I can style them differently.

Ideally, something like: if meta_value for meta_key (jsFeaturedPost) is yes, then add class.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`post_class` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters) is your friend. Just combine it with [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

```
function wpse80098_filter_post_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'yes' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jsFeaturedPost', true ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'my-custom-css-class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse80098_filter_post_class' );
```

Just replace `my-custom-css-class` with whatever class you want to apply to the post container in question.

As noted in the comments, this implementation relies on the `post_class()` template tag being called properly in the post container, e.g.:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

### Edit

Re: this question in the comments:

> Is there a way I can dynamically prepend an a tag to the posts with the featured class?

The easiest method is probably to filter `the_content`:

```
function wpse80098_filter_the_content( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'yes' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_jsFeaturedPost', true ) ) {
        return '<a href="http://example.com">' . $content . '</a>';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse80098_filter_the_content', 99 );
```

Add a very high priority number, so that this filter gets applied last.

Comment: The classes still aren't showing up for the featured posts. These posts are coming from a custom post type if that makes any difference. Here is a pastebin of how I have the template set up: http://pastebin.com/MHKrDQUZ

Comment: You should add the post_class template tag to the post container, in your case `<li id="movie-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>`

Comment: Ah, thank you! I thought the function would add it automatically.

Comment: Is there a way I can dynamically prepend an `a` tag to the posts with the `featured` class? I tried something like this: `$("#all-movies li.featured").prepend('<a href="<?php bloginfo("url"); ?>/hello"></a>');` but realized I couldn't because the `featured` class is being added dynamically.

Comment: @John that's a separate question, and should be asked separately; but I'll add something to my answer.